# Is This a Probability Density Function?

Tags: probability

I was calculating the Fourier transform of a function to be the probability density function of a sequence. I ended up with the following function, but there is no constant C in the calculations do that I make it the normalizing parameter and based on its value consider the function a density function. I was wondering if anyone can help me with coping with this problem or tell me if I can continue without considering the normal constraint. 
$$
p(x,t) = \frac{\exp \left( -\frac{(x+at)^2}{bt} \right)}{\sqrt{bt}}
$$
Where $a, b$ are constants. Thanks!

Comment: You are off by a factor of $\sqrt \pi$.

Comment: So, because there is no constant to take care of that, I can't call it a probability density function right?

Comment: Correct.  Try matching the pattern of $\exp(-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2))/\sqrt{2\pi}$ to your formula.  Clearly you want $bt=2\sigma^2$.

Comment: It can't be matched actually, it is the answer of an inverse Fourier transform equation, meaning I can't just add a constant to it. I would have no explanation for that additional constant in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the gaussian distribution in terms of x. You can even view t as constant the same way you view a and b when treating this as a probability.

Edited (Thanks to J.G.):

So this is a Gaussian with mean at $-at$ and standard dev at $\sqrt{\frac{bt}{2}}$ based on the terms in the exponent, but then the normalization would be wrong this case. Unless we are solving for specific value of a,b to make this normalize correctly, this would not be a valid pdf.

Comment: No, the standard deviation is $\sqrt{bt/2}$.

Comment: What about the Normal criteria? I don't think it posses that one since a, b are fixed.

Comment: @J.G. you are right, will correct

Comment: @J.G.,@gdlamp: I divide the function by 1/2pi to get the normality constraint right! and call it a rescaling. Could the results be far from the original ones?

Comment: @kepler Your PDF should be $p/\sqrt{\pi}$. (In fact, the first comment on the question noticed this.)

Comment: @J.G. I have divided by a number to get the normality,  my question is if I can call it a rescaling and do so, or it just changes everything.

Comment: @kepler I think you mean divided to get unitarity, but it's called normalization. Rescaling would imply replacing a CDF $F(x)$ with one of the form $F(ax+b)$ where $a\ne0$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, I did it for the sake of normalization, to get a PDF. Does this change that I made at the end, dividing the resulted function by appropriate constant , makes a whole a lot of differences in my calculation, and would the probabilities that I am about to get have a lot of error?

Comment: @kepler The only correct calculations are those obtained from a PDF that integrates to $1$.